# Addition of velocities in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

How does one add velocities in general relativity?  If I have a particle with a given four-velocity $u_\alpha$ and a metric $g_{\alpha \beta}$ (for example, a Keplerian orbit around a Schwarzschild BH, in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates), and I want to add a radial velocity to the particle, how is the resulting four-velocity calculated?

Let's say, $u_\alpha = \gamma \{v_t, v_r, v_\theta, v_\phi\}$, where $\gamma = (1 - u_i u^i)^{-1/2}$.

Can I just add to the radial component $v_r \rightarrow v_r + \delta v_r$, and then recalculate $\gamma$?  Or, do I need to apply a Lorentz transformation?  If so, how do you write a Lorentz transformation in an arbitrary metric?

Comment: What do you mean by "add a velocity"?  Typically, operations like that are only defined at a point, and for a sufficiently small 4-d neighborhood around a point, the local spacetime is equivalent to minkowski.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, I see your point.  In my particular case, I have a particular model for the motion of this particle (a given four-velocity), and I would like to consider a slightly different trajectory in which the radial component is modified by some $\delta v_r$.  I guess this boils down to needing to know how to adjust the other velocity-vector components to compensate for the radial change?  I've tried to edit my question a little to clarify.

Comment: *If so, how do you write a Lorentz transformation in an arbitrary metric?* You don't. You apply a Lorentz transformation to the tangent space at one point, i.e., to vectors in an infinitesimal neighborhood.

Comment: @BenCrowell I don't know what you mean

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix: There is no such thing as a Lorentz transformation in general relativity.

Comment: The question is unclear, but if I intepret it corrctly, what you need to do is add the radial velocity to the four velocity of the particle at a given point. Then, assuming that the particle was free, solve the geodesic equations with the new initial velocity.

Comment: @MBN "solve ... with the new initial velocity" based on the energy-parameter (associated with the time-like killing vector)?

Comment: @BenCrowell - "There is no such thing as a Lorentz..."  I was under the impression these still held but they were pointless as one would need to apply an infinite number of them for any given system.  That is, they can, in principle, still be used in non-inertial reference frames, one just needs to apply an infinite number of them to model, say, a single particle trajectory as a continuous function/path.  Am I misunderstanding this?